# What is an intel wifi "inbox driver"?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, drivers

Intel list the driver for my wireless card (Intel® PRO/Wireless 3945ABG) as an inbox driver. I have no idea what this means or how I am supposed to get hold of it. The intel website specifically states it cannot be downloaded from the website, but gives no indication of the method I should use to acquire it.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24944/Microsoft-Windows-8-and-8-1-support

tl;dr what does "inbox driver" mean?

Comment: I would contact Intel and ask.  Its possible they mean the driver supplied with the actual device.

Comment: [This is for Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds033728) but I'm guessing this term applies across the industry. `Inbox driver is a native driver that is supplied with the Operating System.`